# Is $y=\frac{x^{2}-1}{x-1}\;,\;x\neq1$ belong to two-variables linear equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an equation as below:

$$y=\frac{x^{2}-1}{x-1}\;\;,\;\;x\neq1$$

Question:
Does it belong to two-variables linear equation?

My effort:
The equation can be simplified
$$y=\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{(x-1)}\;\;,\;\;x\neq1$$
$$y=x+1\;\;,\;\;x\neq1$$
The equation above in the form *y = mx + c* but I think it is not belong to two-variables linear equation because there is a hole (1,2) in line graph. Is it true?

Comment: This isn't a function in two variables, so how would it be linear in two variables?

Comment: I thinks he means a linear function that has two parameters ($a$ and $b$). The function looks like $f(x)=ax+b$

Comment: I mean linear equation with two variables that can be written as ax + by + c = 0  or  y = mx + c

Answer (score -1):

If you calulate $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow1}f(x) = 2$
This limit is FINITE!
You can thus create an alternate function $\tilde f$ defined by
$$\tilde f(x)=\left\{
\begin{matrix}
\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}\ \text{ if }\ x\ne1\\
2  \text{ if }\ x=1
\end{matrix}
\right.$$
Which is a continuous function and is equal to $y=x+1$ everywhere

[image: Function plot]

Comment: With the original definition the function $y(x)$ is undefined at $x=1$. Adding $y(1)=2$ to the definition creates a new function that is equal to $y=x+1$ everywhere and so is continuous at $x=1$. But adding $y(1)=0$, for example, would create a function that is clearly not continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: @TheD0ubleT I just look at [link](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/limits-formal.html) and there is a hole in (1,2) point

Comment: @gandalg61 Fixed, Thank you :)

Comment: Okay I see. I have to add y=2 if x=1 to the definition to make the equation belongs to two-variables linear equation. So if x=1 is undefined, the equation cannot be called two-variables linear equation as my effort early. Please correct me if my conclusion is wrong.